# Why does the content of one div cause resizing of other divs on the page?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where if I place a table or form inside one of my box classes, the form/table that contains a good amount of information it causes the other div elements on the page to resize and go out of the order I have specified. How can I fix this?

What I have tried thus far:

- Adding `overflow: hidden;` to all box classes.
- Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container ID.
- Adding a class to try and control the content inside of the div's.

```html
    <div id="container">
        <div id="toprow">
            <div class="box1">
                <h3>Box 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <h3>Box 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                <h3>Box 3</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomrow">
            <div class="box4">
                <h3>Box 4</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box5">
                <h3>Box 5</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box6">
                <h3>Box 6</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

STYLESHEET

```css
    #container {
        height: 96%;
        clear: both;
    }
   
    #toprow {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50%;
    }
    
    .box1 {
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        height: 97%;
    }
    
    .box2 {
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        height: 97%;
    }
    
    .box3 {
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        height: 97%;
    }
    
    #bottomrow {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50%;
    }
    
    .box4 {
        border: 1px solid white;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        height: 95%;
    }
    
    .box5 {
        border: 1px solid white;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        height: 95%;
        resize: none;
    }
    
    .box6 {
        border: 1px solid white;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        height: 95%;
    }
```

Comment: Can you work with fixed height and width values (which would make this a lot easier)? What are the 95%, 97% etc. values supposed to do?

Comment: @pso Yes I can work with fixed height and width. How would I go about that?... I'm sorry I'm not the best with CSS.

Comment: I think first you should summarize again what you want to achieve and understand the code you've written so far and then ask a specific question. You could for example set the boxes `height` to say 50px and then successfully use `overflow: hidden` but is that what you need? You probably want the div's to expand but without affecting the others too much? Maybe flexbox is more suitable for this. I'm not familiar with grids and tables but you could look into these three.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I appreciate it.